# How to resize a child Form inside its parent Panel container?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a set of Forms:

**`FormMain`**:

[image]

I have a GUI which contains a set of Buttons on the left side.
Each Button is used to display a new Form, according to the user's choice, in a Panel.

**`FormShowP1`**:

[image]

**`FormShowP2`**:

[image]

**`FormShowP3`**:

[image]

When I want to maximize `FormMain`, the Form inside the Panel does not resize.

How to automatically resize multiple child Forms inside the Panel when the parent Form is maximized?

You find as below the initial code:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private static Panel Panel_ { get; set; }

    public FormMain()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.CenterToScreen();
        Panel_= panel;
        OpenChildForm(new FormShowP1(), Panel_);
    }

    private static void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, Panel controlPanel)
    {
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        controlPanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
        controlPanel.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();
    }

    private void BtnShowP1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenChildForm(new FormShowP1(), Panel_);
    }

    private void BtnShowP2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenChildForm(new FormShowP2(), Panel_);
    }

    private void BtnShowP3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenChildForm(new FormShowP3(), Panel_);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Forms (you should have UserControls, btw) are docked inside a Panel: anchor the Panel to all sides.

Comment: How to correct please, can you share an example to improve your solution

Comment: Select the Panel, find its `Anchor` property in the PropertyGrid and select all sides in the ComboBox selector. You can set a `MinimumSize`, if that's preferable.

Answer (score 0):

for `controlPanel` add `Resize` event

change `OpenChildForm` method to :

```
private static void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, Panel controlPanel)
{
   //.......................
   controlPanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
   controlPanel.Tag = childForm;
   controlPanel.Resize += controlPanel_Resize;
   //.......................
}
```

add `Resize` event

```
private void controlPanel_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(Control item in controlPanel.Controls)
   {
      var frm = (Form)item;
      frm.Width = controlPanel.Width;
      frm.Height = controlPanel.Height;
   }
}
```

and for change panel with window resize set **controlPanel** `Anchor Top, Bottom, Left, Right`

Comment: controlPanel is not recognized in the function controlPanel_Resize

Comment: add this line "controlPanel.Resize += controlPanel_Resize;" i put in code

Comment: and set controlPanel Anchor = Top, Bottom, Left, Right